# flex stops working when used inside of ion-slide-box

Tags: ionic-framework, flexbox

Here is the demo
[**flex inside ion-slide-box**][1]

If I uncomment ion slide box, flexbox stops working but works otherwise.

How do I fix this?

Edit:
This is how it looks now:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

However, I was hoping to get this:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: I was going to answer your previous question and it was deleted :P You still want the three items to stretch to 100% equally?

Comment: Okay :). That's right. I want items to stretch equally as per flex what so ever the number  of items is. It is 3 in this case.

Comment: @ManojKumar: Could you please check the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when you add `<ion-slide-box>` the ionic-framework generates a dynamic class `.slider` which does not have a height set. Thus the child elements cannot calculate `height: 100%`

To solve this, set the height for the parent class:

```
.slider {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[**Updated Ionic**](http://play.ionic.io/app/b86c260b5131)

Comment: That was indeed very smart. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have a solution for that. http://play.ionic.io/app/b86c260b5131 Set the `col` to have full height and align the contents. Rules added at the end.